# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.xtext.RuleCall

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

After upgrading Xtext in my Eclipse from 2.3.1 to 2.4.3, I see these errors in the log:

```
org.eclipse.xtext.parser.ParseException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.xtext.impl.KeywordImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.xtext.RuleCall
                at org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrParser.doParse(AbstractAntlrParser.java:105)
                at org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrParser.parse(AbstractAntlrParser.java:84)
                at org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrParser.doParse(AbstractAntlrParser.java:62)
                at org.eclipse.xtext.parser.AbstractParser.parse(AbstractParser.java:32)
                at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource.doLoad(XtextResource.java:162)
                at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource.doLoad(LazyLinkingResource.java:81)
                at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1518)
                at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.XtextDocumentProvider.loadResource(XtextDocumentProvider.java:227)
```

What's causing this? How do I get rid of them?

Comment: A little google-fu turns up [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/461977/) Eclipse forum thread; recommendation is to regenerate Xcore's grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Eclipse Forum post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/461977/), when a grammar `A` extends `B` (`B` is often `Xbase` or `Xcore`), then changes in `B` mean that `A` has to be regenerated.

In my case, I upgraded to a new version of `Xbase`. Hence the need to run the MWE workflow again to update the sources.

Kudos to [Brian S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386178/brian-s) for finding the blog post.